# Con Javascript agregar un botón a una celda de la tabla utilizando un ciclo for

Tags: javascript, mvc

Con `Javascript`necesito crear un `boton` con sus propiedades (`id`, que al hacer `clic`se ejecute una determinada función, y que tenga la `clase` `btn-danger` de`bootstrap`). En cada iteracion del ciclo`for` quiero agregar ese `boton` al `<td>` de la `tabla`. De la forma que lo estoy haciendo no da resultado ya que ni siquiera se muestra el `boton` en la `View`.
Aca les dejo el codigo de `Javascript`

```js
 var tbody = document.querySelector('#tblLibros tbody');//aca le digo que los datos me los va a mostrar dentro de la etiqueta tbody de la tabla #tblLibros
        tbody.innerHTML = '';//limpio siempre el tbody para que cuando vuelva a hacer click en el boton llenar tabla, no me duplique los elementos
        //traigo el array guardado en el sessionStorage
        var id = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("arrayId"));
        var names = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("arrayNames"));//traigo los nombre del libro
        var cantNames = names.length;//calculo cuantos elementos tiene
        //creo el boton eliminar
        var button = document.createElement("button");
        button.id = "btnEliminar";
        button.addEventListener("click", myFunction, false);
        button.innerHTML = "Eliminar";

        for (var i = 0; i < cantNames; i++) {
            //crea una fila para cada nombre de libro
            var fila = document.createElement('tr');//aca creo la fila
            //crea las celdas para fila
            var celdaId = document.createElement('td');//celda para los id
            var celdaNames = document.createElement('td');//celda para nombres
            var celdaButton = document.createElement('td');//celda del boton eliminar
            //aca imprimo cada elemento de arrNames
            var nodoTextoId = document.createTextNode(id[i]);
            var nodoTextoNames = document.createTextNode(names[i]);
            var nodoButton = document.createTextNode(button);
            //agrega los items a las celdas correspondientes
            celdaId.appendChild(nodoTextoId);
            celdaNames.appendChild(nodoTextoNames);//le asigno a c/u de las celdas, el nombre del libro
            celdaButton.appendChild(nodoButton);
            //agrega c/u de las celdas a la fila
            fila.appendChild(celdaId);
            fila.appendChild(celdaNames);
            fila.appendChild(celdaButton);
            //asigna las filas al tbody de la tabla
            tbody.appendChild(fila);
        }

        //guarda el tbody en un una sessionStorage
        sessionStorage.setItem('tabla', $("#tblLibros tbody").html())
    }
```

Aca funcion que muestra el` tbody

```js
 function showTbodyTable() {

        $("#tblLibros tbody").append(sessionStorage.getItem('tabla'));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer un each para realizar el ciclo, de la siguiente manera

```
funciont myFuncion(){
  var table = '<table cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="table table-hover table-bordered "><thead><tr><th scope="col">Campo 1</th><th scope="col">Campo2</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr></tr>';

    $.each( jsonData, function( index,asignacion){

            table += '<tr>';
            table += '<td><button class="boton1 btn" id="'+asignacion.id+'">Boton1</button></td>';
            table += '<td><button class="boton2 btn" id="'+asignacion.id+'">Boton2</button></td>';
            table += '</tr>';

          });

    table += '</tbody></table>';
        $('div#miDiv').html(table);
}
```

Almacenas en la variable table las reiteraciones del `<td>` y al final lo colocas en un div.
Usas el objeto, en este caso, asignacion para acceder a los elementos del json que necesites.

Comment: Gracias @Jack por responder!. Mi idea es solucionarlo con respecto a mi código ya que tengo la estructura armada, solo necesitaría agregar el botón a la celda creada en el for llamada "celdaButton".

Answer (score 0):

**LO SOLUCIONE DE ESTA FORMA:**

Para agregar el `boton` con sus propiedades, primero hice la `tabla` con `Javascript` de esta forma y ademas la muestro en un `div` .

```js
//************************creacion de tabla***********************************//

        var table = '<table cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="table table-hover table-bordered"><thead bgcolor="#2E4053"><tr><th scope="col" style="color:#ECF0F1">Libros 

seleccionados</th><th scope="col" style="color:#ECF0F1">Accion</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr></tr>';

        for (var i = 0; i < cantNames; i++) {

            table += '<tr>';
            table += '<td>' + names[i] + '</td>';
            //Aca agrego el boton eliminar
            table += '<td><button class="btn btn-danger" id="btnEliminar"'+" value="+ idBook[i] +"'>Eliminar</button></td>";
            table += '</tr>';
        };

        table += '</tbody></table>';

//************************Fin creacion de tabla*******************************//

        $('#miDiv').html(table);//muestra la tabla en el div #miDiv

        //guarda la tabla en una sessionStorage
        sessionStorage.setItem('tablaSeleccionados', table);
```

Y aca muestro el `.cshtml` con el `div`donde va a mostrarse la `tabla`

```html
<div id="table-wrapper">
    <div id="table-scroll">
        <div id="miDiv"></div> @*div donde va a mostrarse la tabla*@
    </div>
</div>
```